# getopt for Visual Studio CRT?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getopt

Is there an equivalent to `getopt()` in the visual studio CRT?

Or do I need to get it and compile it with my project?

**Edit** clarification
`getopt` is a utility function in the unix/linux C Run Time library for common command line parsing chores i.e. parsing arguments of the form `-a -b` `-f someArg` etc'

Comment: For those who are not familiar with it (but do know the MSVC++ CRT), it may be helpful to explain what the function does. Can be hard to say if there's an equivalent otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getopt` implementation from the [GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).  It's licensed under the LGPL, which should be compatible with most software projects.  See the file `posix/getopt.c` in the source distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Advice: boost::program_options instead.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: it's nasty, but it suffices, i've used this in place of getopt too

Comment: It has minor nastyness until you get used to it, but then you have a whole bunch of benefits. It's a by-policy standard of cmdl parsing in my company.