# Why am I getting this error (pointer-to error)

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, getopt

I'm new to StackOverflow and I'm just wondering why my C code is giving me this error. I really want this resolved and if someone could explain why this is happening rather then just give me the answer, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
void scanningForWS(int argc, char **argv)
{

int number = 0;
int sflag = 0;
int opt = 0;
int *s = 0;
char *getopt = 0;
char *optarg = 0;

while ((opt = *getopt(argc, argv, "w:s")) != -1) //the *getopt gives me this error
//Error: Expression much have a pointer-to function

{
switch (opt)
{
case 's':
    sflag = 1;
    break;
case 'w':
    number = atoi(optarg);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
}

}
```

It's the while statement, I commented where needed.

***Problem found, but not solved yet. I have found out I don't have unistd.h and I cannot get it. Does anyone know where I can get it?***

Comment: Ohh, so would you suggest me changing the variable declaration to something other then getopt? Or would you suggest changing the getopt in the while statement? I'm fairly new to C and I'm really confused on this error/typo lol

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a variable with the same name as the function and I can't say if you have included the proper header at all.

That's not a function declaration FYI, that line declares a pointer to char and initializes it with the value `0`. The only way your current code makes any sense is if `getopt` is a function pointer, which it is not.

Your code should be:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void scanningForWS(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int number = 0;
    int sflag = 0;
    int opt = 0;
    int *s = 0;    
    /* char *getopt = 0; do not declare getopt as a variable, 
                         just include the header uninstd.h and use it */

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "w:s")) != -1)
        /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Lol, I'm not sure if my VS copy is just buggy :( It tells me now that getopt is undefined.

Comment: It only becomes undefined after I comment out the declaration, if I keep the declaration I get that pointer-to error I got before :/

Comment: @user1886339: `getopt` is a unix function, it does not exist in the VS CRT and it is not standard C.  If you need it look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935455/getopt-for-visual-studio-crt

Comment: @user1886339: There's nothing buggy about your VS copy. It tells you that it is undefined because it is indeed *undefined*. C Standard Library knows nothing about any `getopt` function. And you did not define it yourself. Why do you expect the compiler to somehow magically know what `getopt` is?

Comment: Yup, I finally got it through my head. I don't have the unistd.h library lol, but how can I get it? It shouldn't be too  hard, now can it?

Comment: @user1886339: I gave you a link, use that.

Comment: Hey ed, I'm new to slackoverflow, how do we check messages on this site? I've checked the inbox, but it only shows comments.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `char *getopt;` 
`getopt` is a function from `unistd.h` and by declaring that char pointer you're doing something very weird :)

Comment: Lol I just learned that it's a function, but I can't #include <unistd.h>. Is there a way I can download it from somewhere?

Comment: @user1886339: A header file is not all that is needed, it is simply the interface.  YOu need the library which contains the implementation as well.  Look at the link I sent you.

Answer (score 0):

getopt returns an `int`, not `int *`.

Remove the `*` from the use in while loop:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "w:s")) != -1) //the *getopt gives me this error
```

to:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "w:s")) != -1) //the *getopt gives me this error
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I still have the same error. Nothing changed :(

Comment: @user1886339 Seems you are declaring a pointer with the same name `getopt`. To use the standard getopt, just include `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: Oh boy, one problem after another lol. If I put #include <unistd.h> it gives me an error saying: cannot open source file unistd.h